# Written Very Basic APEX Class, How Can my Customers get to access it?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, salesforce-service-cloud, apex

I am very new to Salesforce Apex. I created a simple Apex-Class to get all contacts in the salesforce website.

I used javascript code to invoke that class as follows

```
function runApex() {
  sforce.interaction.runApex('AccountRetrieval', 'getAccount', 'name=Rajeev', callback);
}
```

It's working fine in my laptop. But how can my customers get to access that class to get all their contacts ?

Comment: Run the same JS as you?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't simply give them access to the contacts tab in the UI to achieve what you're after then you can create a visualforce page with a custom controller. In the controller, use SOQL to run a query for all Contacts and save the result to a list or map. You can then use this variable to pass the Contact data to the visualforce page. If you just want to dump the data to the page as HTML then you can use a list variable to hold the query result and an apex:repeat tag to generate the HTML on the visualforce page. If you want more control over how the data is displayed then you could also use the apex variable to pass the data to a javascript variable which you could then build your HTML from client-side in whatever way you like.

More detail would be needed to give you full steps on how to set this all up exactly how you want but basically you should use a visualforce page to give them an interface to run your apex code from. Access to that page can be controlled via profiles or permission sets.

If this page needs to be visible to people who do not have a user account to log into your org then you can use the Salesforce feature called Sites to expose content to them without the need for a login.